# @ControllerAdvice not throwing exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I am handling exceptions globally in CustomHandler class. I could see while debugging this class is catching exceptions, but not throwing them to client. Please let me know what i am missing...

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> constraintValidationException(
        ConstraintViolationException e) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
        details.add(violation.getMessage());
    }
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Validation Failed", details);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
        details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Validation Failed", details);
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

Comment: And what is the actual behavior? Please show incorrect responses and stacktraces if there are any.

Comment: Could you please share [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with what @SergVasylchak asked for ?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own application specific exceptions and handle them. E.g: `public class MyAppEx extends RuntimeException {}`. Catch the Exception.class and then throw your exception:

```
try {
    // something goes wrong
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MyAppEx("details of the exception");
}
```

Replace:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyAppEx.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(MyAppEx ex, WebRequest request) {..}
```